# Creating Sign Up View page in SWIFT with A UIImage profile picture setup, Using NEXT as Return Key and UIImage setup not working

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uitextfield, uipickerview, uidatepicker

I am building an app with which my focus is on User Friendly.

In the SignUpViewController, i have a profilePic of type UIImage, Four standard UITextFields to record user's data, and Two more UITextField which activates a UIDatePicker and a UIPicker.

I'm experiencing some problems such as;

1) The UIImage doesn't clip to bounds to give it the round sort of look
2) When i use the UIImage to fetch image from my gallery, it doesn't give me the option to scale my image size and rather gives me a static image pick

3) My UITextFields don't respond to the Next settings i have used. Again, the next setting has been implemented in my LogInViewController and works perfectly. But why isn't it working in the SignUpViewController?

A big thank you in advance.

```
 import UIKit
 import Parse


 class SignUpViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate,      UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {



@IBOutlet weak var profilePic: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lastName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var signUpEmail: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var signUpPassword: UITextField!



@IBOutlet weak var dateTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var genderTextField: UITextField!


var datePicker:UIDatePicker!
var genderPicker:UIPickerView!

var genderSelect = ["Male", "Female"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // PROFILE PICTURE

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "imageTapped:")

    profilePic.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    profilePic.userInteractionEnabled = true

    profilePic.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 170, width: 80, height: 80)

    profilePic.layer.cornerRadius = profilePic.frame.size.width / 2
    profilePic.clipsToBounds = true



    // UI DATE PICKER SETUP

    var customView:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 160))
    customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 160))
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
    datePicker.maximumDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitYear, value: -16, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil)


    customView.addSubview(datePicker)
    dateTextField.inputView = customView

    var dateToolBar = UIToolbar()
    dateToolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    dateToolBar.translucent = true
    dateToolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 246/255, green: 141/255, blue: 17/255, alpha: 1)
    dateToolBar.sizeToFit()
    dateTextField.inputAccessoryView = dateToolBar

    var doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "datePickerSelected")
    var spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    var cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "cancelPicker")

    dateToolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: true)
    dateToolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true



    // UI GENDER PICKER VIEW

    genderPicker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 160))
    genderPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = true

    var customGenderView:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 160))
    customGenderView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()


    customGenderView.addSubview(genderPicker)
    genderTextField.inputView = customGenderView


    var toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    toolBar.translucent = true
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 246/255, green: 141/255, blue: 17/255, alpha: 1)
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    genderPicker.delegate = self
    genderPicker.dataSource = self

    var doneBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "donePicker")
    var spaceBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    var cancelBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "cancelPicker")

    toolBar.setItems([cancelBtn, spaceBtn, doneBtn], animated: true)
    toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true

    genderTextField.inputView = genderPicker
    genderTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar




}



func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if let nextField = textField.nextField {
        nextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    return true
}




  // UIIMAGE TO FUNCTION AS BUTTON WHEN TAPPED

func imageTapped(gesture:UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if let profilePic = gesture.view as? UIImageView {
        showActionSheet()
    }
}

func camera() {
    var myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    myPickerController.delegate = self
    myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    //myPickerController.allowsEditing = true

    self.presentViewController(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func photoLibrary()
{

    var myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    myPickerController.delegate = self
    myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    myPickerController.allowsEditing = true
    //myPickerController.setEditing(true, animated: true)


    self.presentViewController(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func showActionSheet() {
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (alert:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        self.camera()
    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (alert:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        self.photoLibrary()
    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject: AnyObject]) {

    profilePic.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}


// DATE FORMATTING AND CHOOSING

func datePickerSelected() {
    dateTextField.text = datePicker.date.description
    dateTextField.text = self.dateformatterDate(datePicker.date) as String
    dateTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}

func dateformatterDate(date: NSDate) ->NSString {
    var dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
}



// GENDER SELECT

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView:UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) ->Int {
    return genderSelect.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView:UIPickerView, titleForRow row:Int, forComponent component:Int) -> String! {
    return genderSelect[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView:UIPickerView, didSelectRow row:Int, inComponent component:Int) {
    genderTextField.text = genderSelect[row]
}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    return false
}

func genderPickerSelected() {
    genderTextField.text = genderPicker.description
}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}


@IBAction func signUpBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

[image]1.

Tell the imageView to clip to bounds after image assignment. I also suggest altering it's content mode accordingly if desired (aspect fill, fit, etc.)

Edit: Also reset the corner radius.

2. You need to scale images yourself in your didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method. There are lots of different ways to do this, about halfway down this page is one I used a few times: http://www.raywenderlich.com/93276/implementing-tesseract-ocr-ios
3. Did you set the textFieldNameHere.delegate = self anywhere? I couldn't spot it.

Comment: I tried placing the imageView to clip to bounds after the image assignment, no luck. The image in the UIImageView is set to Aspect Fit.                                         I also created a NextField.swift file with an extension of UITextField following this example :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028617/using-next-as-a-return-key  which worked on my LogInViewController but doesn't work in the SignInViewController.  I linked the UITextField delegate in the Main.storyboard.

Comment: Updated answer for imageView

Comment: The code works perfectly on its own. But when compiled in the SignUpViewController, following exactly as you have done, as shown in my code above, i can't seem to get it to work. The idea it to get it all to work within the SignUpViewController class which isn't. Thankyou for your help

Comment: Print out the values of the corner radius or add breakpoints on image assignment and then again when you update the corner radios and clips to bounds, step through each thing and see where it's not getting updated. I would try putting clips to bounds and the corner radius right into the didFinishPickingMediaWithOptions method.

Comment: I just placed the clipsToBounds and the cornerRadius in the didFinishPickingMediaWithOptions method and still no luck. :(

Comment: Maybe try defining the imageView properties in viewWillAppear, I know the context of frames in viewDidLoad aren't set yet. Do you also have it in storyboard? If so, is there a defined height & width?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the storyboard. I double checked and realised my coordinates for my storyboard to that of what i had hard-coded were of slightly different origins. More so, i changed the option in the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo from UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage to UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage. So this part of the problem is fixed.Thanks. However, the others still remains.

Comment: Oh ok, so did you add the scaling image function I linked above? and referring to the Next button and the original answer you need to chain your textFields as described, you have multiple textFields on this view controller so you need to account for all of them, also make sure to assign the delegate to self.