# How to jump to the next flield when "return" is taped in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitextfield, textfield

How i configure cursor to jump to the next *field* (description) when i tap "return" on keyboard in swift?

when I finish to choose the name on field and tap "return" on keyboard

the cursor automatically jump to the "description" field... How i can do this?

[app screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vROE.png)

I tried resolve this problem with this answer but unsuccessful (link:[Using "Next" as a Return Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028617/using-next-as-a-return-key))

Comment: What code did you use when you tried the other answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can respond to changes in the UITextFields or UILabels by setting up outlets to the textfield actions `didEndOnExit`. Then in your implementation of that action outlet you can make your other UITextField active with

```
textField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this exact situation work by creating an action outlet `editingDidEnd` to the textfield. So, in my situation, I'm moving from `firstNameTextField` to `lastNameTextField` when user hits return.

```
@IBAction func firstNameEditingDidEnd(sender: UITextField) {
        lastNameTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
```