# Is it possible use non read-only computed property in extension?

Tags: swift, swift-extensions, computed-properties

Is it possible for a computed property in extension to have both getter and setter? Apple's guide does not mention it and the only example I have seen only shows read-only computed property in extension.

Comment: how do you write a computed property? or do I not understand the question?

Comment: Meaning a computed property with setter, not just getter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible computed property in extension that has getter and setter?

#### Yes.

Probably one of the most common uses of computed properties in extensions in my experience is providing a wrapper to make easier access to particular properties.

For example, when we want to modify the border layer, border color, or corner radius of anything out of `UIKit`, we're stuck going through the `layer` property.

But we can extend `UIView` with a property with both a setter & getter to provide a much more convenient means of changing the properties of its layer:

```
extension UIView {
    var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            guard let color = self.layer.borderColor else {
                return nil
            }
            return UIColor(CGColor: color)
        }
        set {
            self.layer.borderColor = newValue?.CGColor
        }
    }
}
```

Moreover, if we really want to, we can leverage the Objective-C run time to emulate stored properties in extensions (which of course mean setting & getting).  Take part of [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27030181/2792531) for example:

```
private var kAssociationKeyNextField: UInt8 = 0

extension UITextField {
    @IBOutlet var nextField: UITextField? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &kAssociationKeyNextField) as? UITextField
        }
        set(newField) {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &kAssociationKeyNextField, newField, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        }
    }
}
```

This serves as just one example of a property in an extension with a setter & getter.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
extension Bool
{
    public var integerValue: Int
    {
        get
        {
            return true ? 1 : 0
        }

        set
        {
            self = (newValue > 0) ? true : false
        }
    }
}
```

So **yes**.

Comment: So it seems like it's limited only to setter that does not have to make use of stored property to store state.

Comment: You cannot define stored property in extension.

Comment: "that does not have to make use of stored property to store state" confused me for a second. I thought you were talking about accessing properties _inside_ a setter.

Comment: Yes, you cannot define stored properties in an extension.

Comment: @nhgrif: I maintain my statement nonetheless. Manually using the runtime in order to associate a value with an object is not equivalent to defining a stored property in an extension.